# How to validate phone number for billing address in magento2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, validation

How to validate phone number for billing address (should accept only number's and it should not exceed more then 10 digits) in magento2.1.7?

Answer (score 1):

For billing address validation in **magento 2.1.7**, just check out the file path in

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
'telephone' => [
                            'validation' => [
                    //'mobileInD' => true,
                    'validate-number' => 0,
                    'min_text_length' => 10,   
                    'max_text_length' => 10,
             ],
                                'config' => [
                                    'tooltip' => [
                                        'description' => __('For delivery questions.'),
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code :

```
<input type="text" name="billing[telephone]" value="" title="Telephone" 
class="input-text  required-entry validate-length maximum-length-10 minimum- 
length-10 validate-digits" id="billing:telephone" placeholder="Mobile">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Prasad, but i already got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the below validations according to your choice:

```
<validate>validate-length maximum-length-10</validate>
```

And

```
<validate>validate-phoneStrict</validate>
```

For example if you are applying validation form system configuration file then it should be like this:

```
<field id="number" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="9" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Customer Service</label>
                <comment>Please enter an internationalized version of the phone number. For example +91 XXX XXXXXXX</comment>
                <validate>validate-phoneStrict validate-length maximum-length-10</validate>

</field>
```

See more validations [here](https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/add-validation-in-configuration-for-magento2/)

Comment: Thanks Ajwad, but i already got the answer.

Comment: Great, May be helpful for next searchers.